# Is it possible to change field value(+1) into Postgres table by each request?

Tags: postgresql

I decided to make visit counter and change value of table_field by each request. I know that Postgresql has sequences option like "CREATE SEQUENCE...bla-bla-bla.." but i don't know how to hook it with an each request to database table. Is it possible to change value of table  by this way? Does somebody know such thing?
Thank you so much my kind samaritian friend )

Comment: See [Gaps in sequences](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/gaps-in-sequences-postgresql/) for why sequences can/will have gaps and a solution "How to build a gapless sequence" at end. For more options search on 'postgresql gapless sequences'.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea to turn all read operations into write operations just to have some stats. Ideally you should have a dedicated table for stats, and enqueue updates to that table so it is updated asynchronously.

Said that, you can replace your plain select queries by stored procedures, so in the procedure you can do whatever you want and return whatever you want. But I do not recommend that for production for this use case.